# How to notify UI when Entity set ChangeTracker has changes

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, change-tracking

I've created a `WPF` `MVVM` application that does some `CRUD` operation to an `Entity` set.

In the UI I have a save/commit `button`, what I'd like it do is create an event or `notification` in my `ViewModel` to the `View` when `Entity` set `ChangeTracker` has any changes and bind this to `IsEnabled` on the `button`.

How could I achieve this?

I know there is the following property that I could tap into:

```
dbcontext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
```

or

```
db.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added
                                 || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                                 || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
```

I'm just not sure how to implement it

Comment: Create a boolean property in your viewmodel with implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged inteface. Put you customer business logic in getter and setter and then raise property change whenever you need it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think somehow I need to raise a property changed event from dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges, or there-abouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement the following property on the ViewModel:

```
public bool dbHasChanges => dbcontext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
```

And then bind to it in the XAML:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding dbHasChanges}" />
```

It would then be a case of raising a property changed notification on that property whenever the database is updated:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("dbHasChanges");
```

This is for if the database is only changed from within your application (you would execute the above code whenever the user makes a change).

You could also refactor this into a method so you're not hardcoding the property name more than once:

```
private void DBChangeOccured()
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged("dbHasChanges");
}
```

You could then just call this method instead of `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

**Update**

Rather than having a separate method to prevent hardcoding your property names, in .NET Core you can use:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(dbHasChanges));
```